# Why doesn't ASP.NET Core support resource claims in token based authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

So here's what we're doing: we create a backend solution for a large IoT system and every IoT device has an identifier.

Also there are users and when logging in, they get an access token (JWT style + refresh token), which also includes to which IoT device (by their identifier) they have which type of access (example: read data, set configuration, etc...).

We have implemented custom authorization attributes with a system to parse the JWT and determine, if the token bearer has the required access right.

Here's an example:

User "crimson" has "read" and "write" access to device with ID "A599". Looks somewhat like this:

`"sub": "crimson", "dar": ["did": "A599", "arl": ["r", "w"]]`

Forgive me if the JSON is not correct, but I think you see what I'm doing.

Also we have the following custom attribute now:

`[RequiresDeviceAccessRights(deviceIdParameterName: "deviceId", requiredDeviceAccessRights: new [] {"r"})]  [HttpGet]  [Route("/{deviceId}/airpressure")] public ActionResult<AirPressureInfo> GetAirPressureAnalysis(string deviceId)`

I really wonder now why we had to invest like 2 developer weeks into this authorization system when Microsoft claims that "you don't need to create your own authorization attributes, if you do, then we have done something wrong".

Any ideas?

I wanted to have a system for resource claim based authorization using JWT, instead of having to basically hack into ASP.NET Core and "abuse" "use this only for unit testing" Microsoft APIs.

Comment: might be of interest:->https://devtalk360.wordpress.com/2020/04/11/jwt-claim-based-authorization-using-net-core-3-1/

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the codes:

To create the Token:

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }

        public string Right { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Authenticate(UserModel someuser)
        {
            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, someuser.Role), 
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, someuser.Username), 
               new Claim("Right", someuser.Right) 
            };
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

           
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              signingCredentials: credentials,
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
              claims: claims
            );

            string jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            
            return Content(jwtToken);
        }
```

codes in appsettings.json:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",
    "Issuer": "Test.com"
  }
```

Custom requirement:

```
public class WriteRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<WriteRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, WriteRequirement requirement)
        {
            var right = context.User.FindFirst("Right").Value;
            if(right=="Write")
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

       
    }
```

in startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            ...

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateLifetime = false,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                        };
                    });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, WriteRequirement>();
            services.AddAuthorization(opyions => { opyions.AddPolicy("Write", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new WriteRequirement())); });
            ...
        }
```

The Action need Authrization:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
        [Authorize(Policy="Write")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
        }
```

The Result:

[image]